# Many "cannot determine ksym provides" errors when packaging vanilla Kernel (git tag v5.17)

Tags: kernel, kernel-modules, opensuse, rpmbuild

I am trying to build a RPM package for openSUSE Leap 15.2, because I need some special drivers, which are not implemented (or not back-ported) to Kernel `v5.3`. Cloned the [GitHub repository from Linus Torvalds for the Kernel](https://github.com/torvalds/linux). There were not many errors in the imported openSUSE configuration with `v5.17`. Some drivers which are not needed and unsupported module support. I fixed that and the compiling of the Kernel sources worked.

But when I try to build a RPM package from the compiled Kernel modules with...

```
$ make binrpm-pkg
```

...I get many of these errors...

```
error: cannot determine ksym provides of /home/krj/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/kernel-5.17.0_150300.59.54_preempt-1.x86_64/lib/modules/5.17.0-150300.59.54-preempt/kernel/drivers/hid/hid-u2fzero.ko - missing ksym-provides tool.
error: cannot determine ksym provides of /home/krj/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/kernel-5.17.0_150300.59.54_preempt-1.x86_64/lib/modules/5.17.0-150300.59.54-preempt/kernel/drivers/hid/hid-uclogic.ko - missing ksym-provides tool.
error: cannot determine ksym provides of /home/krj/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/kernel-5.17.0_150300.59.54_preempt-1.x86_64/lib/modules/5.17.0-150300.59.54-preempt/kernel/drivers/hid/hid-udraw-ps3.ko - missing ksym-provides tool.
error: cannot determine ksym provides of /home/krj/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/kernel-5.17.0_150300.59.54_preempt-1.x86_64/lib/modules/5.17.0-150300.59.54-preempt/kernel/drivers/hid/hid-viewsonic.ko - missing ksym-provides tool.
error: cannot determine ksym provides of /home/krj/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/kernel-5.17.0_150300.59.54_preempt-1.x86_64/lib/modules/5.17.0-150300.59.54-preempt/kernel/drivers/hid/hid-waltop.ko - missing ksym-provides tool.
error: cannot determine ksym provides of /home/krj/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/kernel-5.17.0_150300.59.54_preempt-1.x86_64/lib/modules/5.17.0-150300.59.54-preempt/kernel/drivers/hid/hid-wiimote.ko - missing ksym-provides tool.
error: cannot determine ksym provides of /home/krj/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/kernel-5.17.0_150300.59.54_preempt-1.x86_64/lib/modules/5.17.0-150300.59.54-preempt/kernel/drivers/hid/hid-xinmo.ko - missing ksym-provides tool.
error: cannot determine ksym provides of /home/krj/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/kernel-5.17.0_150300.59.54_preempt-1.x86_64/lib/modules/5.17.0-150300.59.54-preempt/kernel/drivers/hid/hid-zpff.ko - missing ksym-provides tool.
```

I searched in the openSUSE package manager for the tool `ksym-provides`, but didn't find it. Is this step needed by openSUSE or can I ignore these errors?

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same problem some time back, but recently I've found out the command works and produces a working rpm package. So far, I'm on openSUSE Leap 15.3. Tested Linux version was drm-tip branch of 5.19.